# How to create stiffness (nodal force/displacement) contour plot using Python script in Abaqus?

Tags: python, abaqus

I would like to create a contour plot of stiffness from field output results. For this purpose I have to divide NFORC2 (Y component of nodal force vector) by U2 (displacement in Y direction).

I tried to use Create Field Output --> From Fields where we can define our own output variables. Scalars can be extracted from vectors using getScalarField() but Abaqus shows an error because NFORC is whole element variable while U is nodal variable.

Thus it seems that the only way is to write a script that will convert NFORC. I've found a code that can save a variable as element nodal. It was designed for stress which is calculated at integration points so I'm not sure that it will convert NFORC properly but it's the only option I have so far. It saves some output so I assume that it's correct.

However, Abaqus still doesn't let me divide this new variable by U2. It seems that I have to convert it to unique nodal first. For this I've found another Python script and added it to the first one. Apparently I did something wrong because the error shows up.

Here are the two scripts combined into one:

```
from abaqusConstants import *
from odbAccess import *
import numpy as np

# ***********************************************
odbPath="path_to_odb_file"
stepName="Step-1"
frameNumber=-1 #last frame in the stepName
sourceOutputFieldName='NFORC2' #element forces field
newOutputFieldName='NFORC2_at_NODES_UNIQUE'
# ************************************************
odb=session.openOdb(name=odbPath,readOnly=FALSE)
step=odb.steps[stepName]
frame=step.frames[frameNumber]
sourceField=frame.fieldOutputs[sourceOutputFieldName]
subField=sourceField.getSubset(position=ELEMENT_NODAL)
Values=subField.bulkDataBlocks[0].data
NodeLabels=subField.bulkDataBlocks[0].nodeLabels
NodeLabels_unique, unq_idx = np.unique(NodeLabels, return_inverse=True)
Values_Averaged=np.zeros((NodeLabels_unique.size,Values.shape[1]))
unq_counts = np.bincount(unq_idx)
for i in xrange(0,Values.shape[1]):
    ValuesTemp = [item[i] for item in Values]
    unq_sum = np.bincount(unq_idx, weights=ValuesTemp)
    Values_Averaged[:,i] = unq_sum / unq_counts
newField=frame.FieldOutput(name=newOutputFieldName, field=Values_Averaged)
odb.save()
odb.close()
```

The error I get points to the following line of code:

```
newField=frame.FieldOutput(name=newOutputFieldName, field=Values_Averaged)
```

The error message is: **TypeError: keyword error on field**

Do you know what may be causing the error and how the script should look like?

UPDATE: I finally got this working. Here's the fixed script (odb has to be opened without "Read only" option):

```
from abaqusConstants import *
from odbAccess import *
import numpy as np

# ***********************************************
odbPath="path_to_odb_file"
stepName="Step-1"
frameNumber=-1 #last frame in the stepName
sourceOutputFieldName='NFORC2' #element forces field
newOutputFieldName='NFORC2_at_NODES_UNIQUE'
# ************************************************
odb=session.openOdb(name=odbPath,readOnly=FALSE)
step=odb.steps[stepName]
frame=step.frames[frameNumber]
AllInstances=(odb.rootAssembly.instances.keys())
MyInstance=(AllInstances[-1])
instance1=odb.rootAssembly.instances[MyInstance]
sourceField=frame.fieldOutputs[sourceOutputFieldName]
subField=sourceField.getSubset(position=ELEMENT_NODAL)
Values=subField.bulkDataBlocks[0].data
NodeLabels=subField.bulkDataBlocks[0].nodeLabels
NodeLabels_unique, unq_idx = np.unique(NodeLabels, return_inverse=True)
Values_Averaged=np.zeros((NodeLabels_unique.size,Values.shape[1]))
unq_counts = np.bincount(unq_idx)
for i in xrange(0,Values.shape[1]):
    ValuesTemp = [item[i] for item in Values]
    unq_sum = np.bincount(unq_idx, weights=ValuesTemp)
    Values_Averaged[:,i] = unq_sum / unq_counts
newField=frame.FieldOutput(name=newOutputFieldName,type=SCALAR, description="field")
newField.addData(position=NODAL, instance=instance1, labels=NodeLabels_unique, data=Values_Averaged)
odb.save()
odb.close()
```

The new "NFORC2_at_NODES_UNIQUE" field is correctly created. The only problem now is that when I divide this field by U2 displacement using Create Field Output --> From Fields, I get division by zero error. It's understandable because displacement can be zero in some locations. But what can be done in this case? Perhaps I should convert zeros to some very low values in my script. How can I do this?

Or maybe a better way would be to force the script to return 0 for each encountered division by zero.

Comment: Hi FEA, could I trouble you to provide an example of the error message you are getting? This should help others figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi,

sure, the error points to the following line in the script:newField=frame.FieldOutput(name=newOutputFieldName, field=Values_Averaged) and the message is: TypeError: keyword error on field

Comment: Hi FEA, you can edit your question to include the error so that others can see it in the question. This will also refresh your question to the top of the active questions list.

Comment: Your usage of `FieldOutput` might be the problem. The `field` keyword is supposed to be another `FieldOutput` object. I think in your case you should create the new `FieldOutput` using the variation that takes the name, type, and description arguments. Then use the `addData` methods to add the computed values. You may also want to be careful about using numpy arrays with the Abaqus API. It would be safer to use the data types defined in the Abaqus Scripting Reference.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?.. can't seem to get it myself..

I've tried something like : part1 = odb.Part(name='part-1', embeddedSpace=THREE_D, type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
a = odb.rootAssembly
instance1 = a.Instance(name='part-1-1', object=part1)
newField=frame.FieldOutput(name=newOutputFieldName, description='nodalS11',type=SCALAR)
contigs11 = np.ascontiguousarray(Values_Averaged[:,1])
newField.addData(position=NODAL, instance=instance1, labels=NodeLabels_unique, data=contigs11)
odb.save()
odb.close()
**DOESNT WORK**
http://130.149.89.49:2080/v6.13/books/ker/default.htm is useful 34-34.6

Comment: I updated the question since I finally have a working script. However, another issue arose - I have to convert zero values of U2 to low non-zero values to avoid division by zero error.