# How can I convert zeros in Abaqus field output to very low numbers using Python script?

Tags: python, abaqus

I need to convert all zero values of U2 (displacement in Y direction) to very low but non-zero values so that another output can be later divided by U2 without division by 0 issue.

Here's my attempt to do this:

```
from abaqusConstants import *
from odbAccess import *

# ***********************************************
odbPath="path_to_odb_file"
stepName="Step-1"
frameNumber=-1 #last frame in the stepName
sourceOutputFieldName='U' #displacement field
newOutputFieldName='U2_no_zeros'
# ************************************************
odb=session.openOdb(name=odbPath,readOnly=FALSE)
step=odb.steps[stepName]
frame=step.frames[frameNumber]
AllInstances=(odb.rootAssembly.instances.keys())
MyInstance=(AllInstances[-1])
instance1=odb.rootAssembly.instances[MyInstance]
sourceField=frame.fieldOutputs[sourceOutputFieldName]
subField=sourceField.getScalarField(componentLabel="U2")
Values=subField.bulkDataBlocks[0].data
NodeLabels=subField.bulkDataBlocks[0].nodeLabels
for value in Values:
  if value==0:
     value=1e-9
newField=frame.FieldOutput(name=newOutputFieldName, type=SCALAR, description="field")
newField.addData(position=NODAL, instance=instance1, labels=NodeLabels, data=Values)
odb.save()
odb.close()
```

The script runs without errors and the "U2_no_zeros" field is created but it contains the same values as the original U2 field so the loop doesn't work. In fact, this loop is just my loose idea since I don't know exactly how it should be realized. I was expecting some errors leading to the right solution but for some reason the script runs with no error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing the data inside the `Values` variable. And use `concatenate` method from `numpy` to shape the data correctly. 
And lastly, `addData` method accepts the data to be in tuple format.

```
import numpy

Values = numpy.concatenate(subField.bulkDataBlocks[0].data)
# use concatenate to --> [[..],[..],...] to [......]

NodeLabels=subField.bulkDataBlocks[0].nodeLabels
for i,value in enumerate(Values):
  if value==0:
     Values[i] = 1e-9
newField=frame.FieldOutput(name=newOutputFieldName, type=SCALAR, description="field")
newField.addData(position=NODAL, instance=instance1, labels=NodeLabels, data=tuple(Values))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, when running this code, I get the "illegal argument type for built-in operation" error pointing to the following line: `newField.addData(position=NODAL, instance=instance1, labels=NodeLabels, data=tuple(Values))`

Comment: There must be a type mismatch for one of the argument. Please check the types of the arguments. Please refer [this document link](https://help.3ds.com/2018/English/DSSIMULIA_Established/SIMACAEKERRefMap/simaker-c-fieldoutputpyc.htm?contextscope=all&id=79a86636030642a48592150b58a20019) to know the type of argument.

Comment: The position, instance and labels arguments should be fine, I used them also in my previous script (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287171/how-to-create-stiffness-nodal-force-displacement-contour-plot-using-python-scr) just with some modification to node labels. However, I'm not sure about the data argument. According to the documentation, it's supposed to be "a sequence of sequences of Floats specifying the data values". I use 'tuple(Values)' here, according to your suggestion.

Comment: ahh. Sorry for the mistake. We must use tuple of tuple, that's what they mean by `a sequence of sequences`. So, change `Values` variables as `new_vals = tuple((float(i),) for i in Values)`. And use `new_vals` variable as argument to the `data` option in `addData` command.